# What's TableName.MYD.filepart file in MySQL table (myisam engine)

Tags: mysql, myisam

I got a TableName.MYD.filepart in MySQL Database ( myisam engine)

```
Anyone can figure out what's that file for? Appreciate!
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you transfer the table files with SCP ? Could mean your transfer was interrupted while copying and this file is the temporary file created before the transfer completed.
(Maybe should be on ServerFault ?)

Comment: yes,the databases was copied using SCP, may be there was some wrong during the procedure , I'm not the one who copy it ! Thank you dude!